# Plot X-Axis: Make xticklabels cover a fixed range of bins?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using a tikzpicture plot. I have around 50 bins in my plot. The bins belong to two groups of data sets.
I want to add 2 labels for the x-axis. The first one should cover bins 1-25 and the second one bin 26 to 50.

Can I somehow define two labels with the xlabel or xticklabel parameter and tell them to center themselves in a bin-range?

I tried to draw the x-axis labels by hand, but apparently I can't draw in the negative area of a plot? I tried it like this: `\filldraw[fill=blue] (9.1, -5) rectangle (15.9, -9);`

The screenshot shows how its supposed to look. There are two descending dataset groups, the first one is labeled Dataset A, the second one Dataset B. If it would 20 bins each, the labels would (ideally) center themselves in the middle of their respective bin rage. If I can enter them hardcoded somehow it would be fine, too. [image]

This is my minimal-working example of what I got so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\definecolor{OgAns}{rgb}{0, 0.8, 0.4} 
\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
3   30
1   44
4   26
2   39
5   90
6   80
7   80
8   50
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[   
            ybar stacked,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=100,
            bar width=5pt,
            legend style={at={(0.35, -0.4)},anchor=south west},
            legend columns=-1            
          ]
          \addplot[ybar,fill=OgAns]  file {testdata.dat}; 
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a minimal example of your setup, and possibly a mock-up of what you want the final result to look like?

Comment: Updated example and mock-screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

I got this from the pgfplots manual on page 197 under section 4.9.2 *Alignment of Axis Descriptions*. Basically I added two nodes located at a certain percentage of the xtick range (where the first tick is 0% and the last is 100%) and labeled them. I kept the dots for you to help align the labels. Below is your adjusted working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\definecolor{OgAns}{rgb}{0, 0.8, 0.4} 
\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
3   30
1   44
4   26
2   39
5   90
6   80
7   80
8   50
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        clip=false,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=9,  
        ybar stacked,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=100,
        bar width=5pt,
        legend style={at={(0.35, -0.4)},anchor=south west},
        legend columns=-1                       
      ]

    \node[anchor=near xticklabel,font=\large]
        at (xticklabel cs:0.28) {Dataset A};
    \fill (xticklabel cs:0.28) circle(2pt);

    \node[anchor=near xticklabel,font=\large]
        at (xticklabel cs:0.73) {Dataset B};
    \fill (xticklabel cs:0.73) circle(2pt);

    \addplot[ybar,fill=OgAns]  file {testdata.dat};  
    \end{axis}        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image: pdflatex output]